# ProgressBar в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, progress-bar, recyclerview.adapter

Логика приложения следующая. Прилага парсит первую страницу новостного портала и отображает ее в `RecyclerView`, как только пользователь прокручивает список до конца - идет парсинг второй страницы и отображение следующей пачки новостей в списке и тд (бесконечный список новостей). Но я не понимаю, как вставить `ProgressBar` в конец списка, чтобы он отображался до того момента, пока не загрузится следующая пачка новостей. Я даже не понимаю логику, как это организовать правильно.

Подскажите мне, пожалуйста. Буду очень благодарен! Читаю материал из интернета и все равно не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос очень обширный, поэтому в общих чертах:

Создаете 2 типа айтемов в `RecyclerView`: первый тип -- обычное содержимое, второй -- айтем с прогресс баром (читать по ключу `recycler view two view types`).

Далее, с помощью `OnScrollListener` следите за видимыми в `RecyclerView` айтемами. Как только покажется нужный айтем (например, `(N-2)`-й при размере списка `N`) -- добавляете элемент с прогресс баром и начинаете загрузку данных. Как только загрузка данных завершилась -- убираете элемент с прогресс баром и добавляете данные.

Также здесь стоит не забывать, что загрузка данных может завершиться неудачно и этот случай нужно как-то обрабатывать (например, заменять айтем с прогресс баром на элемент с кнопкой "Try again").

Здесь же необходимо помнить, что при быстром скролле списка, `OnScrollListener`, грубо говоря, может пропускать отрисовку некоторых элементов (т.е. метод `findLastVisibleItemPosition` `LayoutManager`-а вернет, например, `5`, а затем сразу `7`. Это стоит помнить при страте загрузки следующей порции данных на НЕпоследнем элементе. Например, пусть в списке `10` элементов, Вы хотите начинать загружать данные, когда виден `8`-й элемент -- в этом случае при отображении `8`, `9` и `10` элементов нужно проверять, стартовала ли загрузка, и, если не стартовала, то запускать ее.

Поясню предыдущей абзац на пример:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        if (dy > 0) {
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            Log.d("SOME_TAG, "lastVisibleItemPosition: " + lastVisibleItemPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

При быстром скролле списка, в логе Вы можете увидеть, например:

```
...
lastVisibleItemPosition: 6
lastVisibleItemPosition: 7
lastVisibleItemPosition: 10
```

В интернете очень много информации по этой теме (читать по `android recyclerview endless scrolling`).

Вот [здесь](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView) есть неплохая статья.

Answer (score 2):

Не надо мучаться и изобретать велосипеды. Надо просто использовать `SwipeRefreshLayout`, типа:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Далее в коде надо слушать листенер назначаемый вызовом     `SwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener()` и в нем реализовывать логику обновления новых записей.

Выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]